# Is using parameterized in just the login script enough?

Tags: php, sql, code-injection, parameterized

More of a risk assessment question than technical.

So i have been reading a lot about protecting against SQL Injection. Lets assume i have a large web application that is mostly unprotected and i need to make some improvements to protect against this problem.  Read large as lots of SQL interaction using dynamic queries but on few (less than 100 registered users).

My question is... If i have already secured the main login script (the only publicly available user input) using parameterized queries, is it really that necessary to do the same work for the rest of the site?  I mean if a potential attacker can't log in, how much other damage can he do?

Assuming of course none of my registered users have malicious intent.

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming of course none of my registered users have malicious intent.

Never assume that :) If your users have different rights, one with almost no right could find the way to get admin access... And so on.

Also, protecting against SQL injection does not make your login bulletproof and someone could bruteforce through it or simply have sniffed packets from your *trusted* users. Make sure you protect your whole application, do not assume that the entry point you planned (login script) is the only one available...

And please use SSL if your website contains or requires any sensitive data from your users.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you sure that none of the legitimate users won't attempt to attack your system?

I'm glad my bank don't think that.  Some-one would have emptied my account by now, just by using sql injection attacks.

And even then you should be careful about accidents.  If you use parameterised queries, someone using a `'` in a value won't cause problems.

It allows type safety in your parameters.

It engenders better programming habits.

It allows execution plan caching.  *(Without it, every query with a different parameter will look like a completely different query.  Not only preventing caching of plans for those queries, but over-filling the cache so plans that really can be re-used get discarded.)*

Not only is it more secure, it's more reliable.  Other than experimentation and throw-away code, I can think of no project where I would have condoned not using parameterised queries.

Answer (score 0):

Never trust your users!

Even if you do (and nobody can sign up either), there's always the potential of CSRF for instance; an attacker would lead users of that system to a seemingly harmless page with an image. That image would have the following code:

```
<img src="http://yourserver.com/profile?user_id='; DROP TABLE users" />
```

My hacking skills are practically zilch, but you can imagine what would happen :)